# Как сохранить результат метода в переменную для дальнейшего использования?

Tags: php

В общем не пойму как сделать так что бы сохранять результат метода в переменную для дальнейшего испольхования одного и того же значения в других методах. Все работает только результат метода reg_id () все время вычисляется, а мне нужно одно и то же значение этого метода. Как быть подскажите.

```
  public $territory;

public function getReg()
{
    $db = DB::getInstance();

    $query="SELECT ter_address, reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where ter_type_id = 0 AND ter_pid <=> NULL";

    $result=$db->query($query);

    if (!$result) {die($db->error);}

    $reg_id=[];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $reg_id[]=$row['reg_id'];
    } ;
    return $reg_id;
}

public function reg_id (){
   $territory=(int)self::getReg()[mt_rand(0,count(self::getReg())-1)];
   $territory= $this->clean($this->escape($territory));
     return $territory;
}

public function AutoqualiTowns() // или сюда чёт подставить?
{
   **$territory=$this->reg_id();**
```

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что вам нужно что-то такое:

```
  private $territory; // закрываем прямой доступ снаружи

public function getReg()
{
    $db = DB::getInstance();

    $query="SELECT ter_address, reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where ter_type_id = 0 AND ter_pid <=> NULL";

    $result=$db->query($query);

    if (!$result) {die($db->error);}

    $reg_id=[];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $reg_id[]=$row['reg_id'];
    } ;
    return $reg_id;
}

public function getTerritory (){
   if (is_null($this->territory)) { // проверяем есть ли значение, если нет, то получаем его
      $territory=(int)self::getReg()[mt_rand(0,count(self::getReg())-1)];
      $this->territory= $this->clean($this->escape($territory));
   }
     return $this->territory; // возвращаем значение из БД или RAM
}

public function AutoqualiTowns() 
{
   **$territory=$this->getTerritory();**
```

Comment: тут такое дело я пользуюсь только этим методом в этом классе, Что не получается не получается дать одинаковые значения  reg_id ()   в разные  методы ниже по коду

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, я ничего не понял, написал же коментах что выборка из БД происходит 1 раз. При остальных вызовах берется значение из памяти. Объясните что у вас не получается. Только нормально.